# MySQL as ADO NET Destination causing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, ado.net, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I am a newbie with SSDT. I am trying to import data from a SQL Server database to MYSQL with certain transformations.

If I use a flat file destination, it executes perfectly. As soon as I use the ADO NET destination pointing to MySQL database, it does not work. It works fine if I reverse the direction (putting data from MySQL to SQL Server).

Here is the stack trace of output:

```
SSIS package "E:\Project MMA\MPS Module\OLD Db Files\TestMigration\TestMigration\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0047062 at Simple Test, ADO NET Destination [2]: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ADONETDestination.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
Error: 0xC004701A at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: ADO NET Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004003.
Information: 0x4004300B at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: "ADO NET Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Simple Test, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Simple Test
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "E:\Project MMA\MPS Module\OLD Db Files\TestMigration\TestMigration\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```